# Тематика группы ВК

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

хотел бы узнать, возможно ли как-то методами vk api, получать тематику группы. Перерыл все методы, ничего подходящего не нашёл.

Comment: Вы хотите это именно через API делать?

Comment: @hedgehogues, да именно по API. Ну либо же с помощью requests.

Answer (score 1):

[вот](https://vk.com/dev/groups.getById) ссылка на оф. гайд от вк,обратите внимание на поле `fields`, я с vk_api почти не работал, но, по моему, именно тут нужно копать, посмотрите, что оно возвращает...

Comment: К сожалению - нет, я там всё перекопал ещё вчера. Ничего нужно не нашёл.

Comment: К счастью - да, это то, что нужно по вашей проблеме! Копайте глубже!

Comment: @misdeed, есть метод getCatalog, но это не то. Мне нужно по ид группы, получить её тематику. Смотрел поля fields - там нет ничего подходящего. Если вы нашли решение моей проблемы, прошу его предоставить.

Answer (score 0):

Есть метод [groups.getSettings](https://vk.com/dev/groups.getSettings). Через него можно получить параметр subject, который и является той самой тематикой группы. Но права на использование данного метода имеет только админ группы, параметры который вы получаете.

Comment: Это работает только если ты админ группы. А нужно получить тематику арбитрарной группы.